# Getting Rock, Paper, Scissors to work in discord.js with reactions

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a Rock, Paper, Scissors for my discord bot in discord.js. I attempted to create on but it currently is not working.

I'd like the emojis to disappear once the reaction has been made and am unsure how to do that.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "rps",
  description: "A game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!",
  execute(message) {
    var rps = ["", "", "✂️"]
    const m = message.channel.send("Let's play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors! Please react what you would like to choose with the emojis below!").then((message) => {
      message.react("");
      message.react("");
      message.react("✂️");
    });
    const reacted = promptMessage(m, message.author, 30, rps);

    const botChoice = rps[Math.floor(Math.random()*rps.length)];
    const result = getResult(reacted, botChoice);
    m.clearReactions();

    message.channel.send(`You chose ${reacted} and I chose ${botChoice}`);

    function getResult(choice, botChosen) {
      if(choice === "" && botChoice === "✂️") {
          return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
        } else if (choice === "" && botChoice === "") {
          return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
        } else if (choice === "✂️" && botChoice === ""){
          return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
        } else if (choice === botChosen) {
          return message.channel.send("It's a tie!");
        } else {
          return message.channel.send("You lost! I had fun, let's play again!");
        }
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all reactions using `message.reactions.removeAll()` (note that this requires MANAGE_MESSAGES). I recommend placing this on the line after `function getResult(choice, botChosen) {`