# I am trying to make a rps game but it says promptMessage is not defined for this code, how do i make it defined?

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is the code that I'm using right now. Its an rps command so when you react to either rock, paper, or scissors, the code will randomize if you will win or not. But I need help. The prompt message is undefined and I don't know how to make it defined, so please help!

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === rps){
      var rps = ["", "", "✂️"]
      const m = message.channel.send("Let's play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors! Please react what you would like to choose with the emojis below!").then((message) => {
        message.react("");
        message.react("");
        message.react("✂️");
      });
//this is where the problem appears
      const reacted = promptMessage(m, message.author, 30, rps);
  
      const botChoice = rps[Math.floor(Math.random()*rps.length)];
      const result = getResult(reacted, botChoice);
      m.clearReactions();
  
      message.channel.send(`You chose ${reacted} and I chose ${botChoice}`);
  
      function getResult(choice, botChosen) {
        if(choice === "" && botChoice === "✂️") {
            return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
          } else if (choice === "" && botChoice === "") {
            return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
          } else if (choice === "✂️" && botChoice === ""){
            return message.channel.send("You win! I had fun, let's play again!");
          } else if (choice === botChosen) {
            return message.channel.send("It's a tie!");
          } else {
            return message.channel.send("You lost! I had fun, let's play again!");
          }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you want to define it as? If you just copied and pasted the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310526/getting-rock-paper-scissors-to-work-in-discord-js-with-reactions), it's not working because the function was probably defined outside of the `message` event

Comment: So how do we make it defined? I need help with that.

Comment: The function probably involves a [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) function, so I would start by looking at the docs

Comment: So in my main.js file, I add TextChannel.awaitMessages() on the top?

Comment: No, that's not how the function works. As I said, please look at the docs.